# How to use an API in c using linux distro: ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, linux, api, shared-libraries, ubuntu-16.04

I am beginner in linux and I want to use an API in C language from a certain package. This package has files .h (which contain the prototypes and some defines for using the API) and .so files, as well as .dll for Windows. But I don't know how to manipulate them in order to use properly this API in a single code.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for that package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Include the correct headers for the API.
2. Link to the shared object.

For example, to use `libconfig`:

## main.c

```
#include <libconfig.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  config_t cfg;

  config_init(&cfg);
  config_read_file(&cfg, "example.conf");

  return 0;
}
```

The included header defines the API prototype, but doesn't do the actual linking, for that you need to tell the compiler to link to the library.

```
gcc main.c -o main -lconfig
```

This process will vary depending on the library you intend to use, for most you can use the `pkg-config` utility these days to provide the correct include and linker options for the compiler, for example:

```
pkg-config --cflags libconfig
pkg-config --libs libconfig
```

The CFLAGS and LIBS are seperate as usually you will want to compile object files and then link, for example:

```
gcc -c $(pkg-config --cflags libconfig) main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o -o main $(pkg-config --libs libconfig)
```

Note: libconfig doesn't have any CFLAGS, but most libraries do, these will usually be the path to their headers.

Comment: Good answer, UV from me. I'd also add that `pkg-config` is not always available and some libraries do not have a `.pc` file for `pkg-config` and in general you should check the documentation of the library you want to use. The documentation tells you how you should link against the library.

Comment: The library I intend to use is MSPDS, MSP Debug Stack, a stack of libraries: http://www.ti.com/tool/mspds. @Geoffrey the way you suggested me is a dynamic linking, right? I saw a code at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-dynamic-libraries/ explaining how to use shared object by dynamic loading.

Comment: @Sara M, dynamic loading is entirely different from what you asked here. It involves using dlopen and function pointers.